# Prove continuity and find norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let **c** $\subset l^{\infty}$ represent the subspace of real convergent sequences, so for each $a=(a_{1},a_{2},...)\in$ **c** we have a limit $h(a)=lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$.

I am asked to prove that $h(a)$ is a continuous linear functional on **c** and also find its norm.

The linearity part was obviously simple, but I'm a bit stuck regarding the rest. I've tried using Holder's inequality (it helped with another similar problem) but to no avail. Thought I might use the fact that the sequence is Cauchy, but I couldn't think how to do this either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: it is really easy to show that $h$ is bounded.  Another hint: its norm is 1, can you see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i). The absolute value of $\lim_na_n$ cannot be more than $\sup_n|a_n|,$ so $|h(a)|\leq \|a\|.$

(ii).  If $a_n=1$ for all $n$ then $h((a_n)_n)=1=\|(a_n)_n\|.$